# adjust mouse sensitivity in openSuSe

Tags: linux, mouse, opensuse

I'm running openSuse 13.1 with KDE but this seems to be a problem with more Linux distros:

I have a gaming mouse which has a little more resolution than is comfortable for desktop use, so I'd like to slow it down a bit.

In the KDE settings I have inputs for mouse acceleration but not for sensitivity. I even tried setting acceleration <1 but that is ignored.

I found a tutorial fom 2010 for Ubunto and Fedora:

https://patrickmn.com/blog/lowering-gaming-mouse-sensitivity-in-ubuntu-9-10/

...but xinput does not exist on my system

Yast does not seem to have mouse-specific settings at all. There seems to be something in /etc/X11/ but I wouldn't know where to put what -- also it seems a little ridiculous that Windows offers a mouse sensitivity setting via GUI since forever but openSuSe still does not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, the turorial at https://patrickmn.com/blog/lowering-gaming-mouse-sensitivity-in-ubuntu-9-10/ worked -- I just had to install xinput by hand first.

Comment: not the prettiest solution but adding it to ~/.cshrc did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sensitivity setting in the mouse preferences.

[image]

Comment: That's Gnome, though, isn't it? Will that setting carry through to KDE?

Comment: Nope, at least for me it doesn't. You get one smartypants point -- but I'm still a KDE guy